Intelliphense en VsCode no detecta tipos de datos en vistas de PHP
Primero aclaro: el problema es solo del editor, el programa me funciona correctamente.
Función para llamar una vista:
function view($view, $data = [])
{
    extract($data);
    include VIEWS . $view . ".php";
}

Me explico con un ejemplo:
Supongamos que mediante un controlador, llamo a homepage.php y le paso $products usando view().
Desde dentro del archivo homepage.php, cuando voy a usar la variable $products el Intelliphense me marca como que la encontró "unset".
Para solucionarlo estoy haciendo esto (siguiendo con el ejemplo):
<?php
/** @var array $products
 */
?>

Después de estar rato explicándole la situación a ChatGPT, parece que entendió y dijo: "Cuando usas extract(), el editor puede no ser capaz de inferir el tipo de las variables extraídas automáticamente."
Espero que haya alguna solución para no tener que andar indicando el tipo a cada rato.

Actualmente así como lo haces es la forma, más info acá y acá. Podes aplicar la sintaxis IIFE (PHP v7+) pero es básicamente azúcar sintáctico.
